# Cannot find module '@capacitor/core'.ts(2307)

Tags: ionic4, capacitor

When I integrate Capacitor for the first time in ionic framework.

Error comes on this line:

```
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
```

*Cannot find module '@capacitor/core'.ts(2307)*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The quick solution found [here](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/getting-started)

```
$ npm install --save @capacitor/core @capacitor/cli
```